# How to handle very sparse vectors in Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, sparse-matrix

What is the best way to handle sparse vectors of size (about) 30 000, where all indexes are zero except one index with value one (1-HOT vector)?

In my dataset I have a sequence of values, that I convert to one 1-HOT vector for each value. Here is what i currently do:

```
# Create some queues to read data from .csv files
...
# Parse example(/line) from the data file
example = tf.decode_csv(value, record_defaults=record_defaults)

# example now looks like (e.g) [[5], [1], [4], [38], [571], [9]]
# [5] indicates the length of the sequence
# 1, 4, 38, 571 is the input sequence
# 4, 38, 571, 9 is the target sequence
# Create 1-HOT vectors for each value in the sequence
sequence_length = example[0]
one_hots = example[1:]
one_hots = tf.reshape(one_hots, [-1])
one_hots = tf.one_hot(one_hots, depth=n_classes)

# Grab the first values as the input features and the last values as target
features = one_hots[:-1]
targets = one_hots[1:]

...
# The sequence_length, features and targets are added to a list
# and the list is sent into a batch with tf.train_batch_join(...).
# So now I can get batches and feed into my RNN
...
```

This works, but I am convinced that it could be done in a more efficient way. I looked at SparseTensor, but I could not figure out how to create SparseTensors from the `example` tensor I get from `tf.decode_csv`. And I read somwhere that it is best to parse the data after it is retrieved as a batch, is this still true?

[Here](http://pastebin.com/rRbCfU2K) is a pastebin of the full code. From line 32 is my current way of creating 1-HOT vectors.

Comment: Alternatively: How can I create the 1-HOT vectors out of the examples **after** I have pulled a batch of examples (if I just pass the examples directly into the batch)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of dealing with converting your inputs to sparse 1 hot vectors, it is preffered to use [`tf.nn.embedding_lookup`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.12/api_docs/python/nn.html#embedding_lookup), which simply selects the relevant rows of the matrix you would multiply by. This is equivalent for multiplication of the matrix by the 1-hot vector.

Here is a usage example

```
embed_dim = 3;
vocab_size = 10;
E = np.random.rand(vocab_size, embed_dim)
print E
embeddings = tf.Variable(E)
examples = tf.Variable(np.array([4,5, 2,9]).astype('int32'))

examples_embedded = tf.nn.embedding_lookup(embeddings, examples)

s = tf.InteractiveSession()
s.run(tf.initialize_all_variables())
print ''
print examples_embedded.eval()
```

Also see this [example](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/im2txt/im2txt/show_and_tell_model.py#L226) in im2txt project, for how to feed this kind of data for RNNs, (the line saying `seq_embeddings = tf.nn.embedding_lookup(embedding_map, self.input_seqs)`)

Comment: I'm not sure I understood this correctly. Do you mean that I should create and store all the possible 1-hot vectors in advance and then use tf.nn.embedding_lookup to retrieve the ones I need based on the sequence that is read from the dataset?

Comment: I meant to say that you don't need the 1-hot vectors. You can use the indices directly. e.g. the sequence of 1-hot vectors [ 00100, 00001, 01000] would be replaced by a sequence of [2,4,1]

Comment: Ah, I see! But how do I feed this into the RNN? If the 1-hot is multiplied with a matrix to get an embedding, which is then sent into the RNN, then I understand how it could be done with `tf.nn.embedding_lookup`, but I don't understand how to do it when the 1-hot should go directly into the RNN.

Comment: In that case, you can use an identity embedding matrix. However, it is *very* uncommon to feed high dimensional data directly into the RNN. The common practice is to have an embedding matrix that first reduces the dimension of the input.

Comment: Yes, but I am trying to compare my model to another model, which got better results without embedding, so I would like to try without embedding first.
I tried to create an identity matrix but it was too big. I get an error: `Ran out of memory trying to allocate 5.23GiB`

Anyways, is it possible to create 1-hots after I dequeue a batch? So that I convert the batch to 1-hots instead of storing 1-hots in the batch queue. Or will the performance be similar either way?

Comment: The embedding identity matrix would have to be sparse. But this operation or slicing are not yet comply with sparse tensors [see here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/1588). I would suggest you to recheck the other model. I doubt it uses a high dimensional input directly to the RNN, since it would make that model extremely large